# How to get route distance with Mapquest.js?

Tags: javascript, routes, leaflet, distance, mapquest

I am writing a code to find the optimum route. I am using L.mapquest and I am getting the route plot on leaflet. However, I need the distance and time of such route but I can't figure out how to do this. Can someone help me, please?

The following is a piece of code:

```
function findRouteForWaypoints(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    L.mapquest.key = config.MY_API_TOKEN;

    var dir = L.mapquest.directions().route({
      start: ''.concat(startPointLatitude,',',startPointLongitude),
      end: ''.concat(endPointLatitude,',',endPointLongitude),
      waypoints: binWaypoints,
      optimizeWaypoints: true
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the route callback function to get other route parameters like distance.
https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.3/l-mapquest-directions-route/